# How do you remove META-INF from minecraft.jar without any manual file deletion?

Tags: jar

How can I remove META-INF from minecraft.jar, without administrator privileges? I can't install new software.

Comment: The problem with<u> <i> Bin</i> </u>Is that sometimes it can't be found in folders. And if you manually delete meta-inf with winrar, it says that the archive is corrupt. It's not just my computer, because I have tried this multiple times on multiple computers.

Comment: I can make a pretty good guess that if you are deleting the META-INF you are playing with mods. Right? Are you using minecraft Forge? If so are running 1.5.x or 1.6.x? If so use the installer which will install forge for you and delete the META-INF and do a little house cleaning.

Comment: When you mean you are not able to install new software do you mean you are not allowed to modify the system or you require elevation to do so? If so you are sort of in luck. As long as you have the JVM installed minecraft should just run. You will need to store the minecraft files in a place where you have access to read and write. Byt the sound of it that is not on the C:\ drive.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not *certain* what you mean by "manual file deleting", but here's how to delete the `META-INF` folder.

You must open `minecraft.jar` in a program which can edit `.zip` files (such as [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)), then delete the `META-INF` folder as you would anything else.  This should not require administrator privileges, as `minecraft.jar` resides inside your home folder, over which you have almost total control.  On Windows, you can reach the correct folder by  pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (the Windows key is the one that looks like the Start menu) and typing `%AppData%\.minecraft\bin` in the text box at the top of the window which appears.

**If you're not comfortable doing this yourself**, you might ask someone with more computer experience to help you.  A program or script could be written to do it for you, but that would require the installation of additional software on your computer (which typically *does* require administrator rights).

Comment: It's actually easier if you hit `Win+R` to open the `Run...` dialog and then type the aforementioned `%AppData%\.minecraft\bin`.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Ben Blank's answer, if you cannot install a zip application as you do not have administrator rights, you could just rename `mincraft.jar`.

As a `.jar` file is just a `.zip` file under another name, and if you are using Windows, which can now open `.zip` files as if they were directories, you can just rename `minecraft.jar` to `minecraft.zip`. You can now delete `META-INF` without installing any further apps. After this, be sure to rename the `.zip` back to `.jar`.

Linux should also have native zip readers, depending on the distro, and the minecraft data directory is in your `/home/[usr]/.minecraft` directory, which may be hidden from your file explorer UI as it starts with a dot.

Comment: Side note: In Ubuntu, you can show "dot files" in the GUI by pressing Ctrl+H.

Comment: ... or by pressing ctrl+L after clicking in a directory (in Gnome, at least), you can edit the location, and manually add the .minecraft extension

Comment: @Maxpm, What do you mean by dot files?

Comment: @Pacerier Dot files are files (or folders) whose names begin with a `.`.  By convention, they're hidden by default on Unix-like systems.

Comment: +1 for the tip about renaming the jar file. Had no idea it was just a zip all along.